# Horizontal navigation bar not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css

My navigation bar doesn't work in Firefox. You can't click on any of the child items. I apologize if I'm putting too much code here, but I really don't know what's causing the issue. I've removed as much of the trivial stuff as I could.

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #879478;
  height: 35px;
}
#navigation {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -10px !important;
}
#nav {
  float: left;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 35px;
  list-style: none;
}
#nav a {
  text-indent: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -1px !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  font-style: normal;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-table;
  margin-top: 1px !important;
  height: 35px;
}

#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;    
}

#nav li {
  float: left;
}
#nav ul {
  display: none;
}
#nav ul a {
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  display: inline-block;
  width: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#nav ul {
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 100 !important;
}
#nav ul li {
  float: none;
}
#nav ul ul {
  width: 141px !important;
  padding-top: 1px !important;
  border-top: 1px solid #6f8059 !important;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -38px !important;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  z-index: 100 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a style="width: 150px !important;">subject 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="blahblah1.html">child 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="blahblah2.htm">child 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome either

Comment: I dont see any scroll bar in any browser.

Comment: Your CSS is hiding the children, not sure what you expect here

Comment: #nav ul {
  display: none;
}

This is hidding child elements.

Comment: Of all the code I thought useful to include, I didn't include:

 #nav li:hover > ul {display: block;} 

It works great in chrome and ie, but doesn't in firefox. What is wrong with this line?

Answer (score 1):

As @Nitin Garg said, `#nav ul { display: none; }` line is hidding child elements.

However, if you want to show childs element on parent li hover, you have to add this line :

```
#nav li:hover ul {display: block; }
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not having included that code, but I do have:
#nav li:hover > ul {display: block;}
It works great in chrome and ie, but doesn't in firefox.